# Prevent Xcode from indexing a lot of JSON files and include them separately to make Xcode faster

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, lottie

I am working with the iOS library [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) and my problem is that if I add more than 10 Lottie json animations into Xcode it gets stuck. I have actually more than 100 JSON files which I want to use for animation however Xcode is indexing all those files for index highlighting.

If I click on one of those json files by mistake then Xcode crashes. This happens because those JSON files are being loaded in Xcode as if they were Swift classes. I am forced to download those JSON files from a CDN in order to get it to work but I want them to be saved locally.

However I have noticed that downloading those files take too long and my animations do not work how they should. Sometimes they don't even play due to the latency of downloading.

My question is how and where should I store these JSON files properly in Xcode? What is Apple's recommendation? How can I add a bundle programmatically so those files are not being indexed within Xcode?

Why can't I save json files in a .xcassets asset catalog and load it from Lottie? Lottie does not recognize that those are json files and instead handles them as something really strange. So this seems not to be a solution.

I have had this problem for a few weeks and I really don't have any clue what to do. Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: `lottie` animation will run on only main thread. so, be sure while playing it will be on main thread. and one more thing there you trying to download all json at one. instead of this you will do on click download and parse in it `lottie` animation in view.

Comment: wow cool for this information! Are you really sure that lottie is always working in the main thread? i will consider this and will look whether this helps. thanks a lot for this information!

Comment: yeah because i am working on before 3 month and on other thread it will stuck or crashed.